# Android widget badge creation

Tags: android, android-widget, android-notifications

I looked up [this library](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger/blob/master/README.md) which lets the developer overlay the app icon with a badge. Can it be used to overlay a widget? Is there any other coffee example that lets you overlay a widget with badge as simply as this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This won't work on widgets. Widgets implement their on view so no luck here.